# Highcharts custom x-axis categories aligned center (Under the pins)

Tags: highcharts

I am setting custom categories inside the x-axis, once I do that however, the x-axis labels lose their alignment (no longer under the pins)

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
```

This produces

[image]

but what I am after is (with the labels as 'Jan' 'Feb'..etc)

[image]

Is there a way to achieve that with custom categories?
Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lydc94n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set [axis.tickmarkPlacement](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement) to `'on'`.

```
xAxis: {
 categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lydc94n/3/